# Line-In Mixer very quiet

Tags: mixer, amplifier

I bought the [Rolls MX42 Stereo Mixer](https://rolls.com/product/MX42) to mix the output of multiple devices together.

I have connected my Computer (internal soundcard), Laptop, and Phone. All by using 3,5mm Jack to 2 Cinch y-Adapter cables. The output is connected to my Headset ([Sennheiser Game One](https://www.amazon.de/Sennheiser-Gaming-Headset-offener-Akustik-schwarz/dp/B00JQDOALC)), also via a 2 Cinch y-Adapter with a female port.

The setup works and I can mix the audio from all input devices together, but the resulting output is very quiet on the headset.

I'm quite new to this audio stuff but reading the specs of the mixer, it says

> Input Impedance: 10K to 47K Ohms
> Output Impedance: 2.5K to 10K Ohms

which looks to me like a lot of "volume" is "lost" in the mixing process. Am I right in assuming that the output signal needs to be boosted (*amped* ?) before it goes to my headphones? If so, what kind of device am I looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a passive mixer. The only elements in the signal path are resistors (potmeters), so the output signal is going to have a lower volume than the input.

The mixer is built for line-level signals, so the resistance values have been chosen with that in mind. This isn't optimal for headphones signals, which are intended for lower resistance values.

You can do two things:

1. buy a headphone amplifier and connect it to the output of your mixer.
2. replace the mixer with an active mixer that has a headphones output.